# Giving HTML tags a custom class or id in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how can I provide a custom classes for example to `<img>` and `<a>`?
I need to add some `bootstrap` classes to **both** of those elements for when user creates a `page` it will automatically add `bootstrap` classes.

Here is the `HTML` code that is rendered upon creating a new `page` in WordPress

```
<article id="post-18" class="post-18 page type-page status-publish hentry">
  <p><a href="https://readmore.com">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p>
    <img class="alignnone size-medium" src="https://placehold.it/250x250" width="250" height="250"></p>
  <p><a href="https://readmore.com">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
  <p>Morbi lacinia...</p>
  <p>Nullam commodo...</p>
  <p>Maecenas rutrum...</p>
</article>
```

How do I make it to look like this? Take note on `<img>` and the **second** `<a>` child in this `HTML` code sample. I've added a `<div>` before `<img>` (This is how I want it to be)

```
<article id="post-18" class="post-18 page type-page status-publish hentry">
  <p><a href="https://readmore.com">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet....</p>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
    <p><img class="alignnone size-medium img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/250x250" width="250" height="250">
    </p>
  </div>
  <p><a href="https://readmore.com" class="btn btn-primary">Lorem Ipsum</a></p>
  <p>Morbi lacinia...</p>
  <p>Nullam commodo...</p>
  <p>Maecenas rutrum...</p>
</article>
```

I'm using a template called **HTML5 Blank WordPress Theme** [link](http://html5blank.com/)

Comment: Instead of just giving me negative points, please tell me where did I make mistake in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images, you can do this

```
function custom_class($class){
    $class .= ' additional-class'; // Concatenate custom class with the existing class.
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','custom_class');
```

Reference [is here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108831/add-css-class-to-every-image). I use this method when I used bootstrap for WordPress themes.

For links, you can do this with javascript/jquery but it **is not reliable** because it will add class to all the anchor tag.

**Javascript Approach**

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
a.classList.add('btn  btn-primary');
```

**Jquery approach**

```
$('a').addClass('btn btn-primary');
```

Please let me know if you found any issue.

Comment: I managed to get it working in different way, but thanks anyway. I found a field `Image CSS Class` while editing the post, and for the `<a>` I switched to to the `Text` tab and added there. Pity I can't make it automatic, but oh well, thanks for you help anyways.

Comment: The approach that I gave will add class to all images no need to do it manually give that a try.

Comment: Ok, but where do I put that code for images? Is it in `Theme functions`? Do I need to add `<?php ?>` before that? I'm new to `PHP`, sorry.

Comment: Put that code in functions.php yup it should be inside a php tag

Comment: It will surely work because I am using in my theme as well. Give that a shot and reply if any issue.